# EmberJS: Use AJAX data from parent resource in child route

Tags: ember.js

Let's say that I want to create an ember app that displays a matrix and allows
you to click on a cell for more information.  My routes look like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("data", function() {
    this.route("cell", {path: ':row/:col'});
  });
});

App.DataRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.DataModel.create({
      /* information needed for AJAX query */
    });
  },
});

App.DataCellRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.Object.create({
      row: params.row,
      col: params.col
    });
  },

  serialize: function(model) {
    return {row: model.row, col: model.col};
  },
});
```

Furthermore, the matrix load is expensive (say, a slow AJAX request), so I
don't want to have to reload the data when I transition to the child route.
Also, assume that the data in the cells can't be serialized, so I can't just
pass the cell data in the URL.

Here's what the controllers looks like:

```
App.DataController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  model: null,
  content: Ember.A(),

  loadData: function() {
    self = this;
    $.ajax({
      /* ... */,

      success: function(data) {
        App.beginPropertyChanges();
        self.clear();
        data.forEach(function(row) {
          self.pushObject(row);
        });
        App.endPropertyChanges();
      },
  }.observes('model'),
});

App.DataCellController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: 'data',
  model: {row: 0, col: 0},

  matrixBinding: 'controllers.data.content',

  cell: function() {
    var xy = this.get('model');
    return this.get('matrix')[xy.row][xy.col];
  }.property('matrix.@each', 'model'),
});
```

When you click on a cell, its view tells `DataController` to send an event that
transitons to `data.cell` with the appropriate row/column.  I expected that
when I transition to the `data.cell` route, I should have access to
`DataController`'s `content`.  However, all I get is the default empty array.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

To answer the question 'how is `DataController.content` set', I updated the
question to show a more accurate depicition of `DataRoute` and
`DataController`.  Basically, `DataController` has a model that contains
information pertinent to the AJAX request.  I have a function, `loadData`,
which observes the model and loads `content`.

Comment: when does `content: Ember.A()` get set? and how?

Comment: I edited the question to answer your question. Basically, the data controller has a function that observes its model and starts the ajax request.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried accessing `matrixBinding: 'controllers.data.model'` instead of `matrixBinding: 'controllers.data.content'`?

Comment: The model just contains information needed to make the AJAX request, not the data from the request.  I am trying that out now, though; containing everything in the model.